# There are $u$ in $W^{1,p}(D)$ and a weakly converging subsequence $\left\{ u_{m_{k}}\right\} $ to $u$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, sobolev-spaces

Let $D$ be a bounded open subset with smooth boundary in $\mathbb{R}^n$,  $p \in (1,\infty)$, and {$u_m$} be a bounded sequence in $W^{1,p}(D)$. Then there are $u$ in $W^{1,p}(D)$ and a 
subsequence {$u_{m_{k}}$} such that {$u_{m_{k}}$} weakly converges to $u$.

Help me some hints to start.

Comment: You should know a theorem that states, that in reflexive spaces the unity ball is weakly sequentially compact. If not, you should at least know that in separable spaces the unit ball is weakly* sequentially compact. So it remains to show that the $W^{1,p}(d)$ is reflexive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if the sequence $\{u_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}\subset X$ is bounded, where $X$ is a separable normed space, then $\{u_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ possesses a weakly converging subsequence to a $u\in X$, with $\|u\|\le\sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\|u_n\|$, as the closed unit ball in $X$ is weak$^*$ sequentially compact, due to [Banach-Alaoglou Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Alaoglu_theorem)

Answer (score 3):

Follow @Quickbeam2k1 's comment, use Proposition $8.1$ and Theorem $3.18$ in the book Haim Brezis - Functional Analysis, Sobolev Spaces and Partial Differential Equations, we are done.